# How to go to an activity's fragment from an another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a DrawerMenuActivity suppose "AA" and it has 3 fragments "A", "B" and "C" as it's menu. Fragment "A" is my default screen. Now i have navigated to the fragment "B" which has listview items and each item click will open another new activity "AB". In AB there will be a button and that button click will open another activity "AC". so Basically the flow is as follows,

From AA(DrawerMenuActivity) -> "A" fragemnt -> "B" or "C" fragments -> AB(Activity) -> AC(Activity)

Now what i want to do is to return to fragment "B" from the Activity "AC".

I have replaced the fragments of Activity "AA" like this,

in OnCreate(),

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            A fragment = new A();
            replaceFragment(fragment, false, Constants.HOME_FRG_TAG);
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("FROM AC") != null) {
                        updateDisplay(1);
                    }
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10);
        }
```

and for replacing fragments,

```
public void updateDisplay(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String tag = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                clearStack();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new B();
                tag = "B";
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new C();
                tag = "C";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            replaceFragment(fragment, true, tag);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            Log.e("Activity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

replaceFragment() function,

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment, boolean backStackTag, String fragmentTag) {
        try {
            Fragment selectedFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
            if (selectedFrag != null && selectedFrag.isVisible()) {
                return;
            }
            FragmentManager fm = AA.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            if (backStackTag) transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception ", " on adding fragment");
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

and clearStack(),

```
public void clearStack() {
        FragmentManager fm = AA.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
```

in AC Activity i have tried to come back to fragment "B" like this,

```
Intent in = new Intent(AC.this, AA.class);
                in.putExtra("FROM AC", "from ac");
                startActivity(in);
```

now this does what i intend to do but the problem is when it is loading fragment "A" opens for a brief time and then it comes back to the fragment "B".

How Do i navigate to fragment "B" from Activity "AC" properly?? please any help would be appreciated...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First when you go from AB to AC start it as with startActvityForResult, and make sure you don't pass the clear backstack flags. Do it just like this:

```
public static final int REQ_CODE = 1;

Intent in = new Intent(this, AB.class);
startActivityForResult(in, REQ_CODE);
```

So the backstack is not cleared. When replacing the fragments in AA do it like this:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment, boolean backStackTag, String fragmentTag) {
        try {
            Fragment selectedFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
            if (selectedFrag != null && selectedFrag.isVisible()) {
                return;
            }
            FragmentManager fm = AA.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentB).commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception ", " on adding fragment");
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

And when you want to get back from activity AC, set the result to RESULT_OK if you want to navigate back to AA or RESULT_CANCELED if not.

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

In AB, override the onActivityResult method so it sends you back to AA:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

so if RESULT_OK is passed, it will go back to AA where the activity was still in onStop() and the state was saved. Also make sure to init your views in `onCreate` and not in `onStart`.

Comment: Hi Drilon, I have tried your way and it looks like it is working fine just a minor problem whenever after fragment "B" opens for a brief time the app goes to the background...what should i do to correct this??

Comment: when fragment replaces from A to B?

Comment: no, whenever i comeback from Activity "AC" to fragment "B". this is what i did, i started the activity AB from the fragement B using startActivityResult

Comment: then i start activity AC from AB using startActivityResult. now for coming back from activity AC to fragment B i set the result in AC like setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK) and finish it, then i receive AC's result in AB in onActivityResult and set it's result and finish it. finally i receive AB's result in fragment B's onActivityResult but as soon as fragment B opens app goes to the background forcefully.

Comment: I am sorry it was my mistake i was finishing my activities before populating the views.. Thanks For your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use startActivityForResult to pass params from AC to AA.It's a little complicated.EventBus may be helpful to you.